# Reduce cost for Table Valued Function - XML Reader in query plan - how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the below SQL Server query:

```
with cte as 
(SELECT DISTINCT refrecid
FROM         docuref
WHERE     ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' and REFTABLEID='78' and typeid='Note')
SELECT     docuref.REFRECID,  Notes = STUFF
                            ((SELECT     CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + cast([NOTES] AS nvarchar(max))
                                FROM         DOCUREF
                                WHERE     REFRECID = Cte.refrecid AND ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
 FROM         Cte INNER JOIN
                        DOCUREF ON cte.REFRECID= docuref.REFRECID
 WHERE     DOCUREF.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' and docuref.REFTABLEID='78' and docuref.typeid='Note'
 GROUP BY docuref.REFRECID,cte.refrecid
```

The Docuref table contains about 40,000 rows. I am trying to combine the Notes column into one record where the RefrecID is the same,

eg if I have below:

```
Refrecid    Recid     Notes
1000        2000      Notes1
1000        2001      Notes2
1000        2002      Notes3
```

I would end up with:

```
Refrecid    Notes
1000        Notes1
            Notes2
            Notes3
```

However, this query takes about 2 minutes to run, so need to cut that down a lot, so it takes only a few seconds. I have looked at the Actual Execution Plan and the item taking the most cost says 'Table Valued Function - XML Reader', with a cost of 91%. See below for actual execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByJMhcb7B

Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

EDIT:
So based on comments from @Shnugo, I used a Temp table to query against and the query running time has gone down from 2 minutes to 3 seconds. The query I am now using is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') Is Not null
Drop Table #TempTable
;
WITH grouped AS
(
    SELECT  dr.refrecid AS REFRECID
    FROM    docuref dr
    WHERE   dr.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'ansa' 
        and dr.REFTABLEID='78' 
        and dr.typeid='Note'
    GROUP BY dr.refrecid
)

select * into #TempTable from grouped

SELECT gr.REFRECID
    ,STUFF(
    (
        SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + cast(dr2.[NOTES] AS nvarchar(max))
        FROM DOCUREF dr2
        WHERE dr2.REFRECID = gr.refrecid 
            AND dr2.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'ansa' 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Notes
FROM #TempTable gr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quick shot, but it might help:

Read this article by Aaron Bertrand:
["Performance Surprises and Assumptions : GROUP BY vs. DISTINCT"](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct)

Change this cte-code

```
SELECT DISTINCT refrecid
FROM         docuref
WHERE     ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' and REFTABLEID='78' and typeid='Note'
```

To this

```
SELECT refrecid
FROM   docuref
WHERE  ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' and REFTABLEID='78' and typeid='Note'
GROUP BY refrecid
```

Using `DISTINCT` the engine will return all rows and filter the final output. Using `GROUP BY` will return a single refrecid and continue with this. Your execution plans might tell you (count of estimated and actual rows), if the set was reduced to single ids *before* or *after* you are calling the `STUFF(sub select with XML)`...

Hint: The best idea was to upgrade to v2017 and use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

### UPDATE: I think this can be put much simpler...

Try it out:

```
SELECT  dr.refrecid AS REFRECID
       ,STUFF(
       (
           SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + cast(dr2.[NOTES] AS nvarchar(max))
           FROM DOCUREF dr2
           WHERE dr2.REFRECID = dr.refrecid --- this was cte.refrecid
             AND dr2.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' 
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
       ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Notes
FROM    docuref dr
WHERE   dr.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' 
    and dr.REFTABLEID='78' 
    and dr.typeid='Note'
GROUP BY dr.refrecid;
```

Or this - but I expect this to be the same...

```
WITH grouped AS
(
    SELECT  dr.refrecid AS REFRECID
    FROM    docuref dr
    WHERE   dr.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' 
        and dr.REFTABLEID='78' 
        and dr.typeid='Note'
    GROUP BY dr.refrecid
)
SELECT gr.REFRECID
        ,STUFF(
        (
            SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + cast(dr2.[NOTES] AS nvarchar(max))
            FROM DOCUREF dr2
            WHERE dr2.REFRECID = gr.refrecid 
                AND dr2.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Notes
FROm grouped gr;
```

### UPDATE 2

From your comment I take, that the solution for you was, to use a two-step approach:

1. Create a temp-table with the filtered IDs
2. Do the expensive action against this reduced list.

Good to know: The query optimizer will not work the query down in the way we might think. This is not a procedural *step-by-step* process. We tell the engine what we want (a formalised description of the result set) and the engine decides how to do this best.

In this case I'm pretty sure, that the compiler did not rechognize, that the thing within `STUFF()` is going to be expensive. Assumably the `STUFF()` was done for each row **before** the `WHERE` and the `GROUP BY` reduced the rows.

A CTE is not the same as a table (although we can use it within the query in the same way). Especiall with CTEs I'd love a hint like `WITH(ForceFirst)` or something like this, which would tell the compiler to create the CTE's set **before** the rest of the query.

In such cases it is best to force the execution's order with a procedural approach (*one-step-after-the-other*).

Comment: The first Group by suggestion still takes about 2 minutes to execute, so no change with that one.

Comment: Second statement took 1 min 45 seconds to execute
Third statement took 1 min 45 secs to execute
So not much change from original. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @Naz How fast is it without the `STUFF(SELECT...)`? How many rows does it return? How many rows are there in the table? Are there indexes on refrecid, actualcompanyid, reftableid and typeid? You might try this in two steps: First read the distinct ids into a temptable and proceed from there...

Comment: @Naz And one more question: Did you check the execution plans for the estimated and the actual row counts?

Comment: so I tried without the STUFF(SELECT...) and I got back 13k rows in less than one second. Total row count in the table is 40k. There is a non-unique non-clustered index on RefcompanyID/TypeID. Also, a clustered index on RefcompanyID/ReftableID/RefrecID.

Comment: For which query should I be checking estimated/actual execution plans?

Comment: @Naz Your clustered index mentions `RefcompanyID`, but your query calls `ACTUALCOMPANYID`? Please clearify... An please try to shift the 13k `refrecid` into a temp table and call the part starting with `STUFF()` against this table. How is the performance for this? This would gain a lot from an index on `refrecid` and `actualcompanyid` as the *correlated sub query* is called 13k times from `DOCUREF`...

Comment: I cannot amend the table as it is a 3rd party system, so the indexes have to remain unchanged. I am creating a view from this query. I will try to shift into a temp table and see how that goes, using refcompanyID through the whole thing rather than actualcompanyid

Comment: Ok so weirdly if I use RecompanyID in the query instead of ActualcompanyId, the query running time is 45 seconds longer - even though there is an index on this field? So I am going back to using ActualCompanyID. I will now try to figure out how to move the original query to a temp table and see if that is quicker or not.

Comment: Ok so I have a winner. Using a temptable massively increases performance - query running time is down to 3 seconds!. Although I dont understand why. I will add amended code into main question. Cheers

Comment: @Naz, great, that you found a solution! For some details see my update 2

Comment: Just noticed an issue, the View statement will not allow the IF check at the start of the statement - any way around this?

Comment: In fact I better start a new question with that instead. Cheers!

Comment: @Naz, that is the major draw-back of a procedural approach: You cannot go the *inline/ad-hoc* route any more... Starting a new question was my suggestion too.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a [singleton text node](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax) (`(./text())[1]`) for the node path. This will help optimize the XML table-valued function in the query plan, which can provide a significant improvement for larger results.

```
with cte as 
(SELECT DISTINCT refrecid
FROM         docuref
WHERE     ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' and REFTABLEID='78' and typeid='Note')
SELECT     docuref.REFRECID,  Notes = STUFF
                            ((SELECT     CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + cast([NOTES] AS nvarchar(max))
                                FROM         DOCUREF
                                WHERE     REFRECID = Cte.refrecid AND ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
 FROM         Cte INNER JOIN
                        DOCUREF ON cte.REFRECID= docuref.REFRECID
 WHERE     DOCUREF.ACTUALCOMPANYID = 'an' and docuref.REFTABLEID='78' and docuref.typeid='Note'
 GROUP BY docuref.REFRECID,cte.refrecid
```

Comment: It cut the time time by 5 seconds, but still too long. So I have just reduced the number of rows the query is dealing with, from 40,000 to about 1,500. Thats the only way I could get performance down to below 10 seconds. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Naz, upload you actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the link to your question.

Comment: I have added the plan link, didnt realise I could do this, thanks for the tip!

Comment: The plan shows 695M rows were touched by the index scan operator because it was executed 12965 times due to the nested loops. You might try the refactoring suggested by @Shnugo along with the change I suggested to see if you get a better plan. If not, add DDL for your table and indexes to your question for more help.

Comment: I would have thought the XML Reader is the issue as it has most of the query cost - 91%? I will try the suggestion by Shnugo

Comment: @Naz, The estimated costs provide a general idea but the actual rows tell the real story.

Comment: Gotcha, guess Ive been reading execution plans wrong for a while. Im an accidental DBA, so still learning. My actual role is a finance team lead

Comment: @Naz I like the *accidental DBA* :-) You are not alone... Execution plans are best taken from right to left...