# How to use an IF statement within a view to drop/use a #Temp Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to create a view, which begins with the following SQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') Is Not null
Drop Table #TempTable
```

I am also rebuilding this #TempTable further on in the view, and then using data in the Temptable for the rest of the query - for better performance. See:

[Reduce cost for Table Valued Function - XML Reader in query plan - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306652/reduce-cost-for-table-valued-function-xml-reader-in-query-plan-how)

However, SSMS is telling me:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'
Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. 
Table names that begin with '#' denote temporary tables.
```

Is there any way to use the IF statement, drop the Temptable, and then use the rebuilt Temptable in the view?

ANSWER - I need to use a stored procedure, not a view.

Comment: You can't. *"A view is a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query"* ([Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-2017)). A View is effectively a pre-compile `SELECT` statement, and that's all it is. You can't use a `VIEW` to perform DDL or DML operations. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve here? Perhaps what you're actually after here is a Stored Procedure?

Comment: Just been researching some more, and a stored procedure is the other way to run the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure is quite different from a view.  A view is simply an encapsulated query.

However, a stored procedure cannot be used in a `SELECT` statement.  You can only execute it using `EXEC`.

What you probably want is a [user-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017) (UDF).  UDFs return a table, so they can be referenced in the `FROM` clause of a query.  Unlike a view, they can contain multiple statements and can have parameters.

As a note, there is no need to delete temporary tables in stored procedures or functions.  If the temporary table is declared in the body of the code, then it is automatically deleted when the code is exited.  However, you might want to use a table variable instead.

Comment: Gordon, the user stumbled over the fact, that a query was taking very long and it helped a lot to split the work in two steps. The OP was thinking, that a CTE was handled like a table. But in the linked question the optimizer assumably did not reduce the set **before** the expensive action took place. An UDF will have the same limitations as a view in this case... Do you know of any trick, how one could force the engine first to execute the CTE and proceed with the reduced set without moving away from *ad-hoc*?

Comment: @Shnugo . . . I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  A UDF can include temporary tables and table variables, so it can similarly be optimized.

Comment: Well, a comment is probably the wrong place to discuss this... When I have time left, I might place a full question... I do not know, if a *multi-statement* UDF would out-trick the optimizer here... To put it abstract: There is a very large set and a expensive operation. But this expensive operation is done against a very reduced set taken from the large set. In some cases the engine will not *see* this and will perform the expensive operation *before* the set is reduced. In such cases I'd like to tell the engine, in which order this should be done.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. However I have been told I cannot create a UDF in our database. So I am going to have to go back to using my original CTE, but use a WHERE clause to restrict the number of rows returned in the CTE so the query can complete in a reasonable time